# JQuery - Animate

Tags: jquery, animation, offset

I have a div that animates on and off from the right. So it slides off and completely disappears, and then slides back on.

What I don't want though, is that when it animates off, I don't want it to completely disappear, I want an offset of the div by 10px.

Anyway of achieving that?

This is the JS:

```
function hideEditorPane(){
    //weaponEditor
    $("#weaponEditor").animate({
        //left: '+=150'
        width: 'toggle'
        }, 500, function(){
    });
}
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#weaponEditor{
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(images/editorPane.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:200px;
    height:342px;
    right:4px;
    top:4px;
}
```

And in the HTML, its just this:

```
<div id="weaponEditor"><a href="javascript: hideEditorPane();">click</a></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: There is probably an easy way of creating that animation by changing the element's absolute or relative position. However, we would need to see relevant portions of your HTML and CSS to offer a really helpful answer to your question.

Comment: How does it currently animate back ? Because it seems it goes off the view port completely Or are you wanting to create that functionality as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One posibility: add `overflow: hidden` to the CSS rules for #weaponEditor, then:

```
function hideEditorPane(){
    //weaponEditor
    var we = $("#weaponEditor"),
        newWidth = (we.width() < 20) ? 200 : 10;
    we.animate({
            width: newWidth
        }, 500, function(){ });
}
```

That will toggle the width between 10 and 200 pixels.

Update: As Intersteller_Coder correctly points out, hardcoding the width in the script is terrible. You want those to stay in the CSS, if at all possible. If toggling the width ends up working for you, consider using the jQuery UI method [toggleClass](http://jqueryui.com/docs/toggleClass/). Set up one class for the collapsed width and another class for the expanded width, then use toggleClass to switch between the two.

Comment: Hardcoding the width? Really ? Seems very inflexible.

Comment: Yeah, I don't much care for that either, but one step at a time, you know?

Comment: This still squishes all my content, EG, if I have "hello world", as it animates away, each letter is on its own line break.

Comment: Can you describe what effect you want to achieve, i.e., what should the collapsed div look like?

Answer (score 0):

Although it's hard to tell without more understanding of what you are trying to achieve I would say that you want to set width to say: 10px instead od using toggle.

Toggle will set width to 0.

So use

```
function hideEditorPane(){
  //weaponEditor
 $("#weaponEditor").animate({
     //left: '+=150'
     width: "10px"
     }, 500, function(){
 }); }
```

for example.

*That is if I understood correctly that you don't want div to disappear completely you want to have 10px of that div left so you can do something with it later (like folding it to and unfolding at a click).*

Comment: This kind of works, but when it animates back off (with the offset) all the content get squished and you can see some of it

Answer (score 0):

`width:'toggle'` is actually shrinking the div from its's original width to 0, not sliding it anywhere.
If you want to keep using this method, then set a `min-width:10px` on the div and it will stop the jQuery from making it any smaller than that.

The code you have got commented out: `left: +=150` is the type of code to use if want to slide it out by a set amount. It would be something like this to slide the div to the left by 500px:

```
function hideEditorPane(){
    //weaponEditor
    $("#weaponEditor").animate({
        left: '-=500'   //<-- however wide the div is, minus 10px.
        }, 500, function(){
    });
 }
```

So obviously, set the amount it slides to the width of the div you are sliding, minus the amount that you want to 'stick out'

Hope this helps.